# access to data ManyToMany django template

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

I try to display a menu category ---> Subcategory ---> products.
I use a context_processor to display all the categories and submenus .
I need to get products based on category and subcategory
I can only display django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager at object ....

```
class Categorias(models.Model):
nome_categoria = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Subcategoria(models.Model):
nome_subcategoria = models.CharField(max_length=100)    

class Product(models.Model):
categoria = models.ManyToManyField('Categorias')
subcategoria = models.ManyToManyField('Subcategoria')
```

context.py

```
def menu(request):
    return {'menucategoria': Categorias.objects.all(),}

def submenu(request):
return {'submenu': Subcategoria.objects.all(),}
```

menu.html

```
{% for c in menucategoria %} 
    <ul>
        <li class="block">
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" id="{{c.id}}" />   
            <label for="{{c.id}}">{{c}}</label>
            <ul class="options">
            {% for p in produtos.subcategoria.all %}                 
                <li><a href="">{{p}}</a></li>    
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Show us the whole error message?

Comment: I believe it is not an error but a warning of the reference object in memory. The post is this ... django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f887c281f90

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for p in produtos.subcategoria.all %}
```

In Python you would get a `TypeError: 'Manager' object is not iterable` exception, but in templates if fails silently...

---

There are some more tweaks to be done... You seem to got it wrong with the `related_name`. Related name is used for **reversing** relationships, not following them. So probably this is what you're after:

```
class Categoria(models.Model):  # singular!
    nome_categoria = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Subcategoria(models.Model):
    nome_subcategoria = models.CharField(max_length=100)    

class Product(models.Model):
    # using ForeignKey instead of ManyToMany. Guessed so because "categoria" is singular, right?
    categoria = models.ForeignKey('Categoria', related_name='produtos')  # plural in related_name, and "products" not "category"
    subcategoria = models.ForeignKey('Subcategoria', related_name='produtos')  # plural in related_name, and "products" not "category"
```

Now you can do stuff like:

```
{% for p in categoria.produtos.all %}

    somestuff...

    {% for sc in p.subcategoria.all %}

    somemorestuff...
```

---

P.S.

You can leave out the `related_name` altogether. A default related name will be used: `product_set` in this example.

Comment: Thanks for frnhr help, but still worked. 
Removed the related_name, deleted the database and still get message django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at ...